# count row of table from data mysql with vb6 ODBC Driver

Tags: mysql, vb6

How do I calculate the number of rows in a table using ODBC DRIVER 3:51 MYSQL functionality of visual basic 6?

Comment: select count(Pkey) from tblname; won't do it?

Comment: i'm try 

query = "select COUNT(data) from sabun" 
rsPo.Open query, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

That is Error

Comment: I dont think its an error because of query. There is problem with your connections.

Comment: [code]
Private Sub Command19_Click()
Dim qu As String
qu = "select COUNT(id) from item"
test.Open qu, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
MsgBox test
End Sub
[code]

According to you how to get the total of rows from the statement above, I'm sorry because I am still very new.

Error display "Type mismatch"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim strDataBaseName As String
Dim strDBCursorType As String
Dim strDBLockType As String
Dim strDBOptions As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection

Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim b as Long
strDBCursorType = adOpenDynamic  'CursorType
strDBLockType = adLockOptimistic   'LockType
strDBOptions = adCmdText         'Options

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection


cn.Open ConnectString()

    With cn
        .CommandTimeout = 0
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    End With

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset       'Creates record set

    strSQL = "select COUNT(id) from item"

    rs.Open strSQL, cn, strDBCursorType, strDBLockType, strDBOptions


if rs.Eof then
   Goto ExitSub    
else
   <Traverse your recordset here>
end if

ExitSub:

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub



Private Function ConnectString() As String
Dim strServerName as String
Dim strDatabaseName as string
Dim strUserName as string
Dim strPassword as string


strServerName = "localhost" 
strDatabaseName = "DatabaseName"
strUserName = "UserName"
strPassword ="Password"

ConnectString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" & _
                "SERVER=" & strServerName & _
                ";DATABASE=" & strDatabaseName & ";" & _
                "USER=" & strUserName & _
                ";PASSWORD=" & strPassword  & _
                ";OPTION=3;"

End Function
```

Try it.